# SQLite case expressions in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Simple question: do case expressions work in Android? 
I'm trying to implement a expression that checks the user value at the insert time and does some modification according to it.  I know the expression is syntactically correct because it works at the SQLite prompt inside the INSERT command. However, when I try to use it in Android (using `SQLiteDatabase.insert()`) the expression is treated as a String. I have also tried to implement it using some of the core SQLite functions and this new expression is also treated as a String. Any thoughts why this happens?

Edit 1: `rawQuery()` is also not an option. The method is ignored. [Here](http://pastebin.com/NbUZPEkn) are the logcat messages that appear to be related to the method call.

Comment: use rawQuery to avoid escaping a do complex stuff with sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but I solved my problem using (despite not being recommended on documentation) `execSQL()`.

Answer (score 4):

The `insert` method treats all values as actual values, not SQL expressions.
So when you use code like this:

```java
cv.put("Col1", "CASE X WHEN 42 THEN 'y' END");
db.insert("Tab", null, cv);
```

then it is assumed that the string is just a string, and that you want exactly this string to be inserted. This results in a SQL command like this:

```
INSERT INTO Tab(Col1) VALUES('CASE X WHEN 42 THEN ''y'' END')
```

If you want to do anything more complex than the simple case that `insert()` was designed for, you must use [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) instead and build the entire SQL statement by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about `insert()`, but `rawQuery()` doesn't seem an option. I already tried and it seems to be simply ignored when the expression is used. I will try again and check if there are any log messages about this.

Comment: If you have a problem with the statement that you give to `rawQuery`, ask a new question.